# how to handle swoole http server memery usage

Tags: php, laravel, http, lumen, swoole

i have a lumen application with too many requests and i used swoole http my swoole http version is

```
"swooletw/laravel-swoole": "^2.6",
```

and here is is my system service

```
[Unit]
Description=Start artisan service for application
After = network.target

[Service]
ExecStart =/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/artisan swoole:http start
Restart=always
RestartSec=3
LimitNOFILE=200000

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

with this configs

```
SWOOLE_HTTP_WORKER_NUM=100
SWOOLE_HTTP_TASK_WORKER_NUM=35
```

when i start service each process of swoole using 0.4 %of my ram but aftger some hours each process using 1.9 %  and more until all of server ram
i want to know what is happening and how to manage that